# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host with windows server 2008R2

Tags: jakarta-mail

I got following error with `java mail on windows server 2008 R2` and `25 port` is enabled on my firewalls inbound rule:

> DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "XXX.XXX.XXX", port 25, isSSL
>   false javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   XXX.XXX.XXX, port: 25;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Get the actual SMTP session debug text by setting the `mail.smtp.debug` property to `true`. You can either read the debug output from the command prompt or set it to output to a file.

Check if your method of authentication is allowed. After it says `AUTH` it should have the permitted authentication options (GSSAPI, DIGEST-MD5, PLAIN, LOGIN).

If it doesn't get to `AUTH` you might be using the wrong port. Usually:

- 25 for SMTP
- 465 for SSL
- 587 for TLS

If you post the debug output, we can probably offer some more tips.